# In a .NET based distributed AWS architecture, can I log jobs through the system with millisecond precision?

Tags: .net, logging, amazon-web-services

I'm building a complex server/worker system on Amazon Web Services. Persistent data is stored on Amazon SimpleDB. Jobs are passed between computers via Amazon SQS. Binary data is referenced in the SQS messages and stored via S3.

I'd like to find or create a logging architecture that can track a single job across multiple EC2 instances so that I can look for problems and inefficiencies as jobs traverse this system. I'm building for speed, and need millisecond precision.

For instance, I'd love to see something like:

```
Job 243439:
Server Initialize API process: 0ms
Server Read job data from SimpleDb: 60ms
Server Create job on simpleDB:    86ms
Server write data to S3:    92ms
Server Write SQS message:    98ms
Worker picks up SQS message: 400ms
Worker reads data from S3:  590ms
Worker finished job:   650ms
Worker writes data to S3: 700ms
Worker writes message to SQS: 750ms
```

In this way, I could look at an individual job, and see an elapsed event log and identify where it could be improved along the way.

I'm currently using .NET for all processes, but would love to build this in a more agnostic way so that the worker roles could be on Linux, and still log in the same way.

Any ideas of how to best tackle this?